# How can I download a file form Azure BLOB storage

Tags: c#, azure-storage

I have large files already on my Azure BLOB storage. Now at the client side and using azure SDK v2.0 I can download the files a stream as described [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/blob-storage/#download-blobs).

My problem is: The SDK only allows me to download the blob as a stream and I want to download my files in chunks to make the downloads resume-able.

Comment: Nobody can answer this question the way it is. You need to describe the problems you're having. Otherwise, the answer is "Use the Azure SDK to do this." That's clearly a pretty pointless answer and not what you're looking for. Help us help you, and we will!

Comment: Thanks Jaxidian, you can check it now.

Comment: Thanks for updating this. It should be reopened soon for people to help you. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [CloudBlockBlob.DownloadRangeToStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.downloadrangetostream(v=azure.10).aspx) to read parts of a blob.